# Java: Create a new array from Class

Tags: java, arrays

I have my `Fila` class with this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Fila {

    private int [] fila;

    public Fila(int[] fila) {
        this.fila = fila;
    }

    public Fila() {

    }

    public int[] getFila() {
        return fila;
    }

    public void setFila(int[] fila) {
        this.fila = fila;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Fila{" +
                "fila=" + Arrays.toString(fila) +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Now I want to create a new Array of int on my main and insert new values inputted by user. My main atm have this code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Fila dimension? ");
        int n = teclado.nextInt();

        Fila [] a = new Fila [n];
        System.out.println("Dimension of Fila: "+a.length);
        System.out.println("Place that you want to add? ");
        int l = teclado.nextInt();

        for (int i = l-1; i <= l-1; i++) {
            System.out.println("Number? ");
            a [i] = teclado.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));

    }
}
```

But I have incompatible types here:  `a [i] = teclado.nextInt();`

What I need to do?

Comment: Fila is a collection of arrays used to produce a file. You need a to be an array of ints or Integers first while you build it, and then you can put it in a file.

Comment: Fila is container for array of ints. What you want to put in it? Array with single int in it?

Comment: @Rich it is Fila, not File

Comment: `a[ ]` is an array that can contain only `Fila` type of objects. You cannot put `integer` in `a[ ]`. This is the reason you are getting the compile error.

Comment: 1. What is this `for (int i = l-1; i <= l-1; i++) {` ?
2. If `Fila` already contains an array of integers, you just need to take them from `teclado.nextInt()`, to put them into an array, then to call the `Fila` constructor using that array.

Comment: Also loop with int i = l-1; i <= l-1; don't make sense. It will iterate only once for any l.

Comment: I think you may want a[I].setFila(teclado.nextInt())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you want:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Fila dimension? ");
        int n = teclado.nextInt();

        int [] a = new int [n];
        System.out.println("Dimension of Fila: "+a.length);
        System.out.println("Place that you want to add? ");
        int l = teclado.nextInt();

        for (int i = l-1; i <= l-1; i++) {
            System.out.println("Number? ");
            a [i] = teclado.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));

        Fila fila = new Fila(a);
        // Do something else with fila here...
    }
}
```

WHen you wrote Fila a = new Fila[n] you are in fact creating an array of Fila objects, and not an array of ints.